# Devise routing issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting a really frustrating error and I think it is a simple fix. In my header, when I try to include a link called "My Account" that routes to the user's profile, I get:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
```

Everything else works in terms of signup/in with devise, and I can get to the user profile page after signing in at localhost:3000/users/1

My link code in the view:

```
<%= link_to "My Account", user_path %>
```

Also, I get the exact same error when trying to route to the edit user profile page at "edit_user_registration_path":

```
<%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_registration_path, class: "prof-btn" %>
```

I also tried:

```
<%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_registration_path(@user), class: "prof-btn" %>
```

But same error.

My routes.rb file:

root to: 'static_pages#home'
   ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
   devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
   devise_for :users
   resources :users

My users_controller.rb:

class UsersController < ApplicationController

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def create
    @user = User.create(params[:user])
end

def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

[image]

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass in the user to the path helper.

```
<%= link_to "My Account", user_path(current_user) %>
```